# Why was this answer on how is Lopinavir + Ritonavir is expected to stop COVID-19 deleted?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers

The question [How is Lopinavir + Ritonavir expected to stop COVID-19?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/22893/43) asked:

> I can't find anything that would explain why the Lopinavir/Ritonavir combination is expected to do anything. Both drugs appear to be protease inhibitors that are fairly specific to HIV, while SARS-CoV-2 isn't even in the same general group of viruses as HIV.

The [answer](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/a/22900/43) I had written (and later deleted by a mod) states that:

> tests [of the Lopinavir/Ritonavir combination] involving the related SARS-CoV and MERS-CoV viruses show promise (but doesn't explain the mechanism posited)

followed by a quote from a scientific study supporting my statement.

I believe this answered the question from an empirical standpoint, with the limitation that it doesn't explain the mechanism posited, as stated in the answer.

So why was the answer deleted?

---

[image: 6]

Note that this question is different from [what's the max length for a quote?](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1153/43), as at that time the answer was link+quote only and the issue raised by the mod who had removed the question was the length of the quote.

Comment: You're using this question to circumvent a comment lock I put in place. Circumventing moderator actions can have consequences. Your question has been answered ad nauseum.